# Attempting to solve this problem more efficiently

Tags: c++, vector, numbers

I read a natural number with at most 9 digits. I have to form a vector with the even digits of that number, in ascending order, with each digit appearing once (example : 98762222 is going to output: 2 6 8). I want to know what optimisations can I add to this code to make it more efficient.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   int x,i,k=0,copy,v[10]={0},j;
    cout<<"x=";
    cin>>x;
    copy=x;
    if (x==0)
        cout<<0;
    while (x>0)
    {
        v[x%10]++;
        x/=10;
    }
    for (i=0; i<10; i=i+2)
    {
        if(v[i]>0)
        {
          k++;
        }
    }
    int w[k]={0};
    if (k>0)
     {  j=0;
        for (i=0; i<10; i=i+2)
          if(v[i]>0)
           {   w[j]=i;
               j++;}
     }

    for (j=0; j<k; j++)
        cout<<w[j]<<" ";
    if (k==0 && copy!=0)
     cout<<"No even digits";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to read the number as a string.  You can convert the digits to internal numeric format by using: `int digit_number = number_as_string[digit_index] - '0';`  Also, `std::string` has methods for erasing digits (characters).

Comment: This program appears to be missing at least one `#include`.  It also uses C99 variable length arrays, which are not C++.  It also reads from `j` before that variable is initialized with a value.

Comment: @Drew the `#include <iostream>` *was* actually in the code - just hidden behind the opening code fence.

Comment: You didn't initialize `j` to `0`.

Comment: What you have looks fine. It's a great hash table solution.

Answer (score 2):

The [`std::set` container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is your friend, here. It automatically sorts its elements and only keeps one (unique) element for each value:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    int64_t x; // You should use int64_t to cover ALL 9-digit numbers
    std::cout << "x=";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::set<int> s; // But each digit will be OK as a plain "int"
    while (x > 0)
    {
        int digit = x % 10;
        if (digit % 2 == 0) s.insert(digit);
        x /= 10;
    }
    if (s.size() == 0) std::cout << "No even digits.";
    else for (auto d : s) std::cout << d << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Example input/output:

```
x=98762222
2 6 8
```